# Number of concurrent processes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

Given a *Pandas dataframe* which represents when some programs **start** to work and when **finish** (i.e. single row - single program):

```
      starts            finishes
2018-01-01 12:00    2018-01-01 15:00
2018-01-01 16:00    2018-01-01 20:00
2018-01-01 16:30    2018-01-01 20:00
2018-01-01 17:00    2018-01-01 21:00
                ...
```

I need to calculate the number of concurrent programs **in every time represented in the table**. The table above becomes next:

```
      time             number_of_conc_progs
2018-01-01 12:00                 1
2018-01-01 15:00                 0
2018-01-01 16:00                 1
2018-01-01 16:30                 2               
2018-01-01 17:00                 3
2018-01-01 20:00                 1                
2018-01-01 21:00                 0 
                     ...
```

If a program *starts* at 12:00 (e.g.) and the current number of processes is *n*, then at 12:00 the number has value *n+1*.

If a program *finishes* at 12:00 (e.g.) and the current number of processes is *n*, then at 12:00 the number has value *n-1*.

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: I do not even know where to start)

Comment: I get it. Wait 5 minutes and I give you the code you need ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# creation of the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ["2018-01-01 12:00", "2018-01-01 15:00"], 
    ["2018-01-01 16:00", "2018-01-01 20:00"], 
    ["2018-01-01 16:30", "2018-01-01 20:00"], 
    ["2018-01-01 17:00", "2018-01-01 21:00"]])
df.columns = ["starts", "finishes"]

# number of progs increases of 1 for start times
starts = pd.DataFrame()
starts["time"] = df.starts
starts["number_of_conc_progs"] = 1

# number of progs decreases of 1 for finishes times
finishes = pd.DataFrame()
finishes["time"] = df.finishes
finishes["number_of_conc_progs"] = -1

# then I merge the starts and the finishes dataframes
result = pd.DataFrame()
result = pd.concat([starts,finishes])
# I sort the time values
result = result.sort_values(by=['time'])
# If there is several starts or finishes at the same time, I sum them
result = result.groupby(['time']).sum()
# I do a cumulation sum to get the actual number of progs running
result.number_of_conc_progs = result.number_of_conc_progs.cumsum()
```